# Is there any rate limit when using the whois command on ips?

Tags: ip, whois, geoip

The data returned by `whois ip-address` appears to be very useful and more accurate than the data I get from the maxmind geoip databsae I am currently using.

Where does the data come from and are there any rate limits?

Of course I will cache information for an ip, but nevertheless I am expecting tens to hundrets of thousands of calls daily.

Please note that I am quering information on IP addresses, not domain names. Therefore the registrars are not involved. The data appears to come from RIPE and ARIN, however they do not write about any limits in their terms and there is also no information available whether the databases are somehow distributed in a DNS like fashion or come from a single server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is certainly a rate limit and it will be in the order of dozens or hundred calls a day, depending on the registrar providing the data for a given TLD.

The [whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) data and database has a completely different purpose and it certainly is not meant to be abused by people not wanting to pay for quality GeoIP database access.

Comment: As I pointed out I do not want to look up domains, I want to look up IPs. So there are no TLDs and no registrars involved. I am aware of the registrar limits.
Also I own licenses for the best database I could find (Maxmind). My problem is not the money, its the quality.

Comment: Read what `whois` data is and where it comes from. Also, start thinking: Do you honestly believe anyone would pay GeoIP providers a single cent if much better data would be available for free elsewhere?

Comment: The manpage of whois says that it comes from the ripe and arin databaes, however they do not write about any limits. Thats why i'm asking.
And I do not believe, I know. I am paying 25 USD every month for data that IS less accurate.